# How to prevent a rewriterule from changing the url to include a querystring when undesired?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop

I am having some trouble getting mod-rewrite rules in my .htaccess file to work like I need them to.

I am trying to translate web requests made from:

`http://www.masterongspropshop.com/blog/22`

To:

`.../blog.php?idPost=22`

When I try, the URL always reverts to `.../blog?idPost=22`.  I have tried a couple of different variations but all of them seem to end with a similar result.

The rewrite rules currently look like this:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [L]
> RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]*)$ blog.php?idPost=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$ blog.php?idPost=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the URL is still being changed somewhere along the way to read .../blog?idPost=22. 

The problem with this is that I have already coded the Facebook like and comments to .../blog/22 which means I would have to start the comments over if I were to change the URL format now.  Another factor is that the site is based on PrestaShop, perhaps the full query string is being re-attached somewhere within the framework.

Comment: Sorry I have no knowledge about prestashop. Can you enable RewriteLog and then provide relevant log snippet here with your question.